# Web Fonts "Normal" font weight

Tags: css, fonts, google-webfonts

Is it still reasonable to assume that font-weight:normal and font-weight:400 are equivalent even when using Web Fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the definitive answer but it will have to do for now - I went through the whole current set of 617 fonts on Google Web Fonts.  From what I can see Normal is always 400.  All current fonts specifiy Normal, 400.

The one thing I should add - there are some WOFF fonts, e.g. Open Sans Condensed, which do not in fact have a "Normal" style at all.  However, this should not break the assumption  of Normal = 400.

Here is an interesting gotcha with Chrome.  It silently replaces font-weight:700 with font-weight:bold.  It doesn't try to do that with the other font weights.  Even so if you are relying on numeric values it is best to put in a silent test that does the requisite replacements.  Something along the lines of

```
var sample = $('#fontSampleA');
var fontwt = sample.css('font-weight');
fontwt = ('normal' == fontwt)?400:(('bold' == fontwt)?700:(('book' == fontwt)?300:fontwt));
```

just in case a future version starts trying to do more silent "smart conversions".

Comment: There might be a possibility that the browser may not read font-weight:normal as font-weight:400.

Comment: If you use the Open Sans Condensed font family the logical way, you declare the “Book” typeface with `font-weight: 300`, and when your document has text with no `font-weight` explicitly set (i.e., it is defaulted to `400`), browsers are required to use the typeface with the nearest available weight. So no problem. If you use the FontSquirrel way, no problem either, since it generates code that declares the “Book” typeface as having weight `normal` (i.e., `400`).

Answer (score 3):

In the value of [`font-weight`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight), `normal` by definition means `400`. This does not depend on font.

Using `@font-face`, it is possible to cheat e.g. by declaring a font face as having normal weight (by defaulting `font-weight`, or by setting it to `normal` or `400`) even though the typeface is in fact bold (or light or whatever). Fontsquirrel @font-face generator does this: it effectively defines each typeface as a font family. Example:

```
/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on January 22, 2013 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'source_sans_probold';
    src: url('sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

This means that an element may have the `font-weight` value of `400`, even though the typeface actually used is bold design.

This is not in any way related to the use of `400` vs. `normal`, and it’s not just the font weight. FontSquirrel plays the same game with `font-style`.

Comment: Thank you. Useful to know this.